# Solving the Global Relationship of the Dampened String $q_{tt} + \frac{\rho}{2} q_{t} - q_{xx}=0$ with the Method of Fokas

Tags: cv.complex-variables, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, wave-equation

I was interested in learning more about the Fokas method for solving partial
differential equations after hearing the impressive claim that it could resolve
any linear partial differential equation. I wanted to try a one-dimensional
dampened wave over a finite interval $[0,L]$ with dynamic boundary conditions
as I believed that would provide a unique challenge.

Here are my notes up until the point I became stuck. (I write in an informal
style to directly record my thought process.) I believe that meticulously typing my
methods over ~2 hours will save you all time in the long run because you may
precisely identify where I went wrong.

$$
    \begin{cases}
    q_{tt} + \frac{\rho}{2} q_t - c^2 q_{xx} = 0 \\
    q(x, 0) = q_0(x) \\
    q_t(x, 0) = q_1(x) \\
    q_x(0, t) + f(t) q(0, t) = 0 \\
    q_x(l, t) + f(t) q(l, t) = 0 \\
    \end{cases}
$$

Right now, the equation cannot be turned into a global relationship because it
is not currently written in divergence form. Ashton's Algorithm guarantees the
existence of fundamental k-forms to any linear partial differential equation.

The adjoint of the linear partial differential operator $\mathcal{L}$ satisfies
$\langle L^{\dagger} u, v \rangle = \langle u, L v \rangle$ and will also posit
an additional solution $\tilde{q}$. If $\mathcal{L}^{\dagger} \tilde{q} = 0$, then
$d\eta = \tilde{q}\mathcal{L}q - q\mathcal{L}^{\dagger}\tilde{q} = 0$ if and only if
$\mathcal{L} q = 0$, producing a candidate for the fundamental k-form.

If $\eta \in \Lambda^{k-1}(\Omega)$ is a ($k-1$)-form, then

$$
    \eta = \sum_{j=1}^{n} (-1)^{j+1} a_j(t) dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge \widehat{dx^j} \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n
$$

will render the compatability condition of the equation as the divergence of $\vec{a}$

\begin{align}
    d \eta &= (\nabla \cdot \vec{a}) dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n \\
            &= (\tilde{q} \mathcal{L} q - q \mathcal{L}^{\dagger} \tilde{q}) dx^1 \wedge \ldots \wedge dx^n
\end{align}

for variables $x^1, \ldots, x^n$. Let $\mathcal{L} = p\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}, \ldots, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\right)$ for a
polynomial $p$,
so that we may write it in multi-index notation as $\mathcal{L} = \sum_{\alpha} c_{\alpha} \partial^{\alpha}$. Both the
divergence and sum are linear operators, meaning that $\vec{a}$ can be permuted by the multi-indices $\alpha$ to produce

$$
    \left(\nabla \cdot a\right)_{\alpha} = \tilde{q} c_{\alpha} \partial^{\alpha} q + (-1)^{|\alpha| + 1} q c_{\alpha} \partial^{\alpha} \tilde{q}
$$

Applying integration by parts to the definition

$$
    \partial^{\alpha} = \frac{\partial^{|\alpha|}}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1} \ldots \partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}
$$

we find that $\langle u, \partial^{\alpha} v \rangle = (-1)^{|\alpha|} \langle \partial^{\alpha} u, v \rangle$. The fact
that the symmetry of $\partial^{\alpha}$ follows the parity of $|\alpha|$ encourages us to study the cases
of even and odd $|\alpha|$ separately. To this end, we introduce the definitions

$$
    [\alpha, \beta] = \partial^{\beta} \tilde{q} \partial^{\alpha} q - \partial^{\beta} q \partial^{\alpha} \tilde{q}
$$

$$
    \{\alpha, \beta\} = \partial^{\beta} \tilde{q} \partial^{\alpha} q + \partial^{\beta} q \partial^{\alpha} \tilde{q}
$$

When $|\alpha|$ is even,

\begin{align}
\nabla \cdot a_{\alpha} &= c_{\alpha} \left(\tilde{q} \partial^{\alpha} q - q \partial^{\alpha} \tilde{q}\right) \\
                        &= c_{\alpha} [\alpha, 0]
\end{align}

and when $|\alpha|$ is odd,

\begin{align}
    \nabla \cdot a_{\alpha} &= c_{\alpha} \left(\tilde{q} \partial^{\alpha} q + q \partial^{\alpha} \tilde{q}\right)\\
                            &= c_{\alpha} \{\alpha, 0\}
\end{align}

The only remaining task is to place $[\alpha, 0]$ and $\{\alpha, 0\}$ into divergence
form. If $|\alpha|$ is even, then there must be an even number (possibly 0) of $\alpha_k$ which are odd;
without loss of generality, we can choose the order of the axes such that the first
$\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{2m}$ (for $m\in\mathbb{N}$) are odd and all further indices are even. This
simplification is justified by the fact that we are only considering a single $\alpha$ and all
terms are well defined under coordinate permutations.

$$
    \alpha = \underbrace{2 \gamma}_{\text{even terms}} + \underbrace{\sum_{k=1}^{2m} e_k}_{\text{odd terms}}
$$

Although his full approach is lengthy, I believe that we only need two main identities for the present equation.

For anticommutative terms, the divergence form arises via

\begin{align}
[\alpha, \beta] &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \left(\partial^{\alpha - e_k} \tilde{q} \partial^{\beta} q - \partial^{\beta} \tilde{q} \partial^{\alpha - e_k} q\right) \\
                &- \left(\partial^{\alpha - e_k} \tilde{q} \partial^{\beta + e_k} q - \partial^{\beta + e_k} \tilde{q} \partial^{\alpha - e_k} q \right) \\
                &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} [\alpha - e_k, \beta] - [\alpha - e_k, \beta + e_k]
\end{align}

while the corresponding formula for even terms is

\begin{align}
    \{\alpha, \alpha + e_k\} &= \partial^{\alpha + e_k} \tilde{q} \partial^{\alpha} q + \partial^{\alpha + e_k} q \partial^\alpha \tilde{q} \\
                             &= \partial^{e_k} \left( \partial^{\alpha} \tilde{q} \partial^{\alpha} q + \partial^{\alpha} q \partial^{\alpha} \tilde{q}\right) \\
                             &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x_k} \{\alpha, \alpha\}
\end{align}

where $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_k}$ means the partial derivative with
respect to $x^k$ with a slight abuse of notation.

We now work to apply Ashton's algorithm to the current problem. Recall that the wave
equation may be expressed as a linear partial differential operator with $x$ being the
first variable and $t$ being the second variable.

$$
    (\partial_t^2 + \frac{\rho}{2} \partial_t - c^2 \partial_x^2) q = 0
$$

The particular $v$ tuples are then $v_1 = (0, 2)$, $v_2 = (0, 1)$, and $v_3 = (2, 0)$.
The domain of integration shall be $\Omega = [0, L] \times [0, \tau]$. $\mathcal{L}^{\dagger} \tilde{q} = 0$, leading the equation
to expand as follows.

$$
    \tilde{q} \mathcal{L} q - q \mathcal{L}^{\dagger} \tilde{q} = [(0, 2), 0] + \frac{\rho}{2}\{(0, 1), 0\} - c^2 [(2, 0), 0]
$$

The second derivative in time can be view written by applying the identity for $[\alpha, \beta]$ with $\alpha=(0, 2)$ and $\beta=(0, 0)$

\begin{align}
    [(0, 2), 0] &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t}[(0, 1), 0] - [(0, 1), (0, 1)] \\
                &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t}[(0, 1), 0] \\
                &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left[\tilde{q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial t} - q \frac{\partial \tilde{q}}{\partial t}\right]
\end{align}

and the same argument ($\alpha=(2, 0)$, $\beta=(0, 0)$) is also useful for the second spatial derivative.

\begin{align}
    [(2, 0), 0] &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[(1, 0), 0] - [(1, 0), (1, 0)] \\
                &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}[(1, 0), 0] \\
                &= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\tilde{q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x} - q \frac{\partial \tilde{q}}{\partial x}\right]
\end{align}

Finally, taking $\alpha=(0, 0)$ and $e_k = e_2$ in the identity for $\{\alpha, \alpha + e_k\}$, we arrive at the definition $\{(0, 1), 0\}$.

\begin{align}
\{(0, 1), 0\} &= \{e_2, 0\} \\
                &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \{0, 0\} \\
                &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (2 \tilde{q} q)
\end{align}

Collating all three identities, we find the general form for $d \eta$ where the adjoint solution is still undetermined.

$$
    d \eta = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} 
    \left(
        \tilde{q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial t} - q \frac{\partial \tilde{q}}{\partial t}
    \right) +
    \rho \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\tilde{q} q) - c^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x} 
    \left(
        \tilde{q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x} - q \frac{\partial \tilde{q}_x}{\partial x}
    \right)
$$

Now, we need to find a dispersion relationship by taking an ansatz of the form
$\tilde{q} = e^{i \vec{\sigma} \cdot \vec{x}}$ for a propagation vector $\vec{\sigma} = (\sigma_1, \sigma_2)$ and position $\vec{x} = (x, t)$. By the
above argument regarding the parity of each derivative, we compute $\mathcal{L}^{\dagger}$ by
reversing the sign of each odd term. After substituting $\tilde{q}$, we arrive at a coupling condition
upon the components $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ that shall produce the dispersion relationship.

\begin{align}
    \mathcal{L}^{\dagger} &= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\rho}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} - c^2 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} \\
    \mathcal{L}^{\dagger} \tilde{q} &= \left(-\sigma_2^2 - i \frac{\rho}{2} \sigma_2 + c^2 \sigma_1^2\right) \tilde{q}\\
    \sigma_1^2 &= \frac{1}{c^2} \left(\sigma_2^2 + i \frac{\rho}{2} \sigma_2\right)
\end{align}

Although I am not sure if this is the appropriate direction, I changed my derivation so that $\sigma_2$ would instead be a function of $\sigma_1$,
so that the resultant integrals would resemble a Fourier transform in space. I believe that this factor will remove the spatial dependence of the
initial position and velocity of the string in the global relationship.

\begin{align}
    \sigma_2^2 &+ i\frac{\rho}{2} \sigma_2 - c^2 \sigma_1^2 = 0 \\
    \sigma_2 &= -i\frac{\rho}{4} \pm \sqrt{c^2 \sigma_1^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2}
\end{align}

Finally, we may express $\tilde{q}$ as a member of the kernel of the adjoint operator $\mathcal{L}^{\dagger}$ by taking $\sigma_1 = \lambda \in \mathbb{C}$

$$
    \tilde{q} = \exp\left(
        i\lambda x 
            + \frac{\rho}{4} t
            \pm
            i
            \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2}
            t
        \right)
$$

so that we express $d \eta$ in our original formula

$$
 d \eta = \tilde{q} \mathcal{L} q - q \mathcal{L}^{\dagger} \tilde{q}   
$$

To show that the solution holds over a domain $\Omega$, we must prove that $d \eta$ vanishes inside
of said domain, which is equivalent to showing its primitive vanishes on the boundary $\partial \Omega$.
In preparation to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$
    \int_{\Omega} d \eta = \int_{\partial \Omega} \eta
$$

we shall express $d \eta$ as a 2-form. It is very important to realize that the
$\rho \frac{\partial}{\partial t} (\tilde{q} q)$ term has the effect of replacing $-\frac{1}{4}\rho$ with
$\frac{3}{4}\rho$.

\begin{align}
    d \eta &= 
    \left[
        \frac{\partial}{\partial t} 
        \left(
            \tilde{q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial t} - q \frac{\partial \tilde{q}}{\partial t}
        \right) +
        \rho \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\tilde{q} q\right) - 
        c^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\tilde{q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x} - q \frac{\partial \tilde{q}}{\partial x}\right)
    \right] dx \wedge dt \\
    &=
    \left[
        \frac{\partial}{\partial t} 
        \left(
            \tilde{q} 
                \frac{\partial q}{\partial t} + 
                    \frac{3}{4} \rho \tilde{q} q
                     \mp i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2}
                 \tilde{q} q
        \right) - 
        c^2
        \frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left(
            \tilde{q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x} 
            - i \lambda \tilde{q} q
        \right) 
    \right] dx \wedge dt
\end{align}

so its primitive $\eta$ as a 1-form will follow from the definition of the exterior
derivative where the arguments to $q(x, t)$ and $\tilde{q}(x, t)$ have been suppressed

$$
    \eta = 
    - \tilde{q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial t} dx 
    - \frac{3}{4}\rho \tilde{q}q dx
    \pm i
    \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2} 
    \tilde{q}q dx
    - c^2 \tilde{q} \frac{\partial q}{\partial x} dt + 
    i \lambda c^2 \tilde{q} q dt
$$

Unfortunately, I do not have an easy way to include an image in my question. Please imagine a rectangle with verticies $(0, 0)$, $(L, 0)$, $(L, \tau)$, and $(0, \tau)$
parameterized in the counterclockwise direction. Integrands shall be as follows.

For all $(x, t) \in [0, L] \times \{0\}$

$$
    \eta(x, 0) = 
    e^{i \lambda x}
    \left(
        -q_1(x)
        -\frac{3}{4} \rho q_0(x)
        \pm i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2} q_0(x)
    \right)
    dx
$$

For all $(x, t) \in \{L\} \times [0, \tau]$

$$
    \eta(L, t) = 
    \exp
    \left(
        i \lambda L + 
        \frac{\rho}{4} t \pm 
        i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2} t
    \right) 
    \left(
        i \lambda c^2 q(L, t)
        -c^2 \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}(L, t)
    \right)
    dt
$$

For all $(x, t) \in [L, 0] \times \{\tau\}$, where the interval $[L, 0]$ indicates $[0, L]$ with the opposite sign
convention in my own idiosyncratic notation.

$$
    - \eta(x, \tau) = 
    \exp
    \left(
        i \lambda x +
        \frac{\rho}{4} \tau \pm i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2} \tau
    \right) 
    \left(
        \frac{\partial q}{\partial t}(x, \tau) +
        \frac{3}{4} \rho q(x, \tau)
        \mp i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2} q(x, \tau)
    \right)
    dx
$$

For all $(x, t) \in \{0\} \times [\tau, 0]$ where once more $[\tau, 0]$ is the same as $[0, \tau]$ but with
the opposite sign convention.

$$
    -\eta(0, t) = 
    \exp
    \left(
        \frac{\rho}{4} t \pm 
        i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2} t
    \right) 
    \left(
        c^2 \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}(0, t) -
        i \lambda c^2 q(0, t)
    \right)
    dt
$$

The integral over $\Omega$ is then equal to

\begin{align}
& 
 \left(
        - \frac{3}{4} \rho
        \pm
        i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2}
\right) 
\hat{q}_0 (\lambda) 
-\hat{q}_1 (\lambda) + \\
& c^2 \exp\left(i \lambda L\right) \int_{0}^{\tau} 
\exp \left(
    \frac{\rho}{4} t
    \pm
    i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2} t
\right) \left(
    i \lambda q(L, t) - \frac{\partial q}{\partial x} (L, t)
\right) dt + \\
& \exp
\left(
    \frac{\rho}{4}\tau
    \pm 
    i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2} 
    \tau
\right) 
\left(
    \frac{\partial \hat{q}}{\partial t} (\lambda, t) +
    \frac{3}{4} \rho \hat{q}(\lambda, t)
    \mp i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2} \hat{q}(\lambda, t)
\right) +
  \\
& c^2 \int_{0}^{\tau} \exp\left(\frac{\rho}{4} t \pm i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2} t\right)
\left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial x}(0, t) - i \lambda q(0, t) \right) dt
\end{align}

Using the following notation,

\begin{align}
\xi_{\pm} (\lambda) &=
\frac{\rho}{4}  \pm 
i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2 }
\\
F_{\pm}(\lambda, x, \tau) &= 
c^2 \int_{0}^{\tau}
e^{\xi_{\pm} (\lambda) t} \left(
    i \lambda q(x, t) -
    \frac{\partial q}{\partial x}(x, t)
\right) dt
\end{align}

the global relationship may be rewritten as

\begin{align}
    & \left(
        \xi_{\pm} (\lambda) - \rho
    \right) \hat{q}_0 (\lambda)
    - \hat{q}_1 (\lambda) + \\
    & \exp \left(
        i\lambda L
        \right)
     F_{\pm}(\lambda, L, \tau) + \\
    & \exp \left( 
            \xi_{\pm} (\lambda) \tau 
        \right)
    \left(
        \frac{\partial \hat{q}}{\partial t} (\lambda, \tau) +
        \left(
            \rho - \xi_{\pm} (\lambda)
        \right) 
        \hat{q} (\lambda, \tau)
    \right) -\\
    & F_{\pm}(\lambda, 0, \tau) = 0
\end{align}

I now need to cancel the unknown boundary conditions by looking for a symmetry in $\xi_{\pm}(\lambda)$. For the case of the
diffusion equation, the dispersion relationship is $i\lambda x - \lambda^2 t$, so the transform $\lambda \to -\lambda$ is respected and suffices
to eliminate the unknown conditions. I am having difficulty finding the corresponding transform for my current equation

$$\frac{\partial^2 q}{\partial t^2} - \frac{\rho}{2}\frac{\partial q}{\partial t} - c^2 \frac{\partial^2 q}{\partial x^2} = 0$$

Question: How do I proceed? Should I try to cancel the boundary terms by looking for a symmetry in $\xi_{\pm}(\lambda)$? Or, should I directly
seek to solve for $\hat{q}(\lambda, \tau)$ via an inverse Fourier transform and deform one of the integrals from $(-\infty, \infty) \times \{0\}$ to $\partial D$ for
$D$ as follows.

$$
    D = \left\{
        \lambda :
        \Re \left(
            \frac{\rho}{4} \pm i \sqrt{c^2 \lambda^2 - \left(\frac{\rho}{4}\right)^2}
            \right) \leq 0 
        \right\}
$$

In that case, how would I simplify

\begin{align}
    \left(
        \xi_{\pm}(\lambda) - \rho
    \right) \hat{q}(\lambda, \tau) & =
    \exp(-\xi_{\pm}(\lambda)\tau)\left(
    \left(
        \xi_{\pm} (\lambda) - \rho
    \right) \hat{q}_0 (\lambda)
    - \hat{q}_1 (\lambda) \right)  \\
    & + \exp \left(
        i\lambda L - 
            \xi_{\pm} (\lambda) \tau 
        \right)
     F_{\pm}(\lambda, L, \tau) \\
    & +
        \frac{\partial \hat{q}}{\partial t} (\lambda, \tau) \\
    & - \exp(-
    \xi_{\pm} (\lambda) \tau 
    ) F_{\pm}(\lambda, 0, \tau)
\end{align}

But then, I do not know how to cancel the term

$$
    \frac{\partial \hat{q}}{\partial t} (\lambda, \tau)   
$$

Should I try to solve for it as well? Or, is there a different avenue
that is better explored?